# How to split the character list when certain character is reached and store it as a string in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, char

Here is my character list items:

```
ALPO..LASS....OBO.PARROT
```

The character array list of items contains a combination of '.' and letters. I want to split the characters when the last '.' is encountered and store the value as string, or pass the extracted string in String array list.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:** (needed in String array list)

```
ALPO
LASS
OBO
PARROT
```

I tried using:

```
for (int i = 0; ....)
{
    ....
    ArrayList<Character> answerchar = new ArrayList<Character>();
    static String outputs;
    outputs += answerchar;
    outputlist.add(outputs);
}
```

But I am getting weird results. Any idea of what should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your char array into a String, then split on literal dots:

```
List<Character> chars; // given a list of 'A', 'L', 'P', 'O', '.', '.', 'L', 'A', 'S', 'S', etc

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(chars.stream().map(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.joining("")).split("\\.+"));
```

If you specifically need an `ArrayList` (not just any list implementation):

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(chars.stream().map(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.joining("")).split("\\.+")));
```

Comment: I am getting output as [[, , A, L, P, O, , , , , L, A, S, S, , etc . Can't I make ALPO as a complete word and store it in string ARRAY LIST @Bohemian

Comment: @Anusha copy paste the regex, which should be exactly as `"\\.+"`. The live demo shows it working

Comment: To convert character array to a string i used String fullop = String.valueOf(answerchar) where answerchar is my character list . Then I used the String 'fullop' to proceed with your answer @Bohemian

Comment: My input will be 'A' ' L' 'P' 'O' and wont be like ALPO . These are the letters in character list. Rather hard coding the value, pass the input to a character list, then try proceeding with that .  I am not getting expected result @Bohemian

Comment: I have characters in CHARACTER LIST and not in CHARACTER ARRAY. When I try executing your code, I got this error - The method split(String) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Character> @Bohemian

Comment: I converted the character list to string using "Stringbuilder" and tried your code and now it works..!! Thanks @Bohemian

Comment: I will try . Thank you and what does the regex split("\\.+") actually does .? Please explain @Bohemian

Comment: I have a problem with this code when I tried testing with this input '...ALPO..LASSO.."  When the first character is '.' and not 'A', its returning some empty value and empty value is added to the string array list . If I test the index of ALPO with this case , its returning '1' because empty value is populated to the array list. @Bohemian

Answer (score 1):

You need to split a String with many '.' , One dot will not work, so you need to split with multiple occurrences of '.'
Try sample code of ->

```
String inputString = "ALPO..LASS....OBO.PARROT";
String[] stringArray = inputString.split("\\.+");
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
}
```

Hopefully this should work.

Edit 1- 
It is working at my end PFA Screenshot of the same.

[image]

Comment: I am getting output as , A, L, P, O, 
, 
, L, A, S, S, O, 
, and I need  words "ALPO" , "LASSO" in string array list

Comment: Please check edited answer, I have added the screenshot of output.

Comment: Can you check by passing the input in character array and test using that array ? I think you are getting because you are hard coding the string @Ajinkya Patil

Comment: What if the input is "....APLO..LASSO.." What if the string starts with '...' ? @Ajinkya Patil